# Create SVG group with JavaScript returns false children.length

Tags: javascript, svg

I try to create a group but it is not working correctly. It returns 1 for the group.length. What did I do wrong?

```
<html>
<body>
  <svg id="test" width="100%" height="100%">
    <svg id="group">
      <g id="g"></g>
    </svg>
  </svg>
  <script>
    var e = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'ellipse'); 
    e.setAttribute('cx', 0);
    e.setAttribute('cy', 0);
    e.setAttribute('rx', 20);
    e.setAttribute('ry', 20);
    document.getElementById('g').appendChild(e);
    document.getElementById('g').appendChild(e);
    document.getElementById('group').appendChild(g);
    alert(g.children.length); // returns 1 though I add it two times
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It should honestly not give you anything. g should be undefined

Comment: It is weird that g has an actual value, I debugged it. Is it a JS reserved word or a fast way to get a element by id?

Answer (score 1):

If the element already exists in DOM, appendChild just moves it to another place. To get 2 elements, you should create 2 nodes and append it. You also can append copy of node:

```
document.getElementById('g').appendChild(e.cloneNode(true));
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild):

> If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position (there is no requirement to remove the node from its parent node before appending it to some other node).

Answer (score 1):

You can't append the same element twice without cloning it, a fast solution is to create a new element inside a loop.

```js
for (i=0; i<10; i++){
  var e = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'ellipse'); 
  e.setAttribute('cx', 0);
  e.setAttribute('cy', 0);
  e.setAttribute('rx', 20);
  e.setAttribute('ry', 20);
  document.getElementById('g').appendChild(e);
  document.getElementById('group').appendChild(g);
}

alert(g.children.length); // returns 10
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <svg id="test" width="100%" height="100%">
    <svg id="group">
      <g id="g"></g>
    </svg>
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```